# Floating point division instead of integer division

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I do:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 4
>>> x/y
0
```

It returns `0` instead of `0.25` because I didn't declare `x` or `y` as a float. But even when I do:

```
>>> x = 0.0
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 4
>>> x/y
0
```

It still returns `0`?

How can I perform floating point division on the integers `x` and `y` without using `float(x) / float(y)`?

Comment: "even if i put x = 0.0 before he return 0 again" - well of course it'll give you a zero, because you put x=0.0 instead of x=1.0.

Comment: `0.0/some_number` should result in the floating point number `0.0` for all python implementations.  Normally in these cases, I'd advise that you `from __future__ import division`, but it's hard to tell if that actually applies here...

Comment: if i put 0.0 in declaration afte the code change the value to 1

Comment: if you write `x=0.0` and then `x=1`, `x` will be an `int` and not a `float`

Comment: also, in python, you do not declare variables

Comment: Worth noting: only one of the variables needs to be a float to perform floating point division. `1. / 4` and `1 / 4.` will both yield `0.25`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put:

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the top of your module. This will make the `/` operator behave as if it's doing float-divison by default; you can use the `//` operator if you still want floor-division.